# Passing TestCafe -t parameters with spaces in Jenkins CI

Tags: javascript, jenkins, npm, e2e-testing, testcafe

Running the following command directly from my IDE (VSCode) works:

[Documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-t-name---test-name) $testcafe ie tests/sample-fixture.js -t "Click a label"

But when I try the same through my CI (Jenkins), it errors because I assume of the spaces in the test name.
Note that all my other parameterized steps are working and they contain no spaces.

**In Jenkins I'm doing:**

Run command: testcafe ie tests/sample-fixture.js -t ${TEST_NAME}

Pass run parameter = "Click a label"

[image]

**ERROR**
No tests to run. Either the test files contain no tests or the filter function is too restrictive.

> npm ERR! ... `"-t" "\"Click" "a" "label\""`

If I then try to pass %20 in place of the spaces, I still get an error.

> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! ... `"-t" "\"Mobile%20menus%20ZDAS\""`

I know this is not a TestCafe issue, but maybe someone in the community has a workaround for this?

**SOLUTION** (in Jenkins execute shell):

This tool is super useful: https://www.shellcheck.net/

```
if [ "${TEST_NAME}" != "All" ]
then
    NODE_ENV=jenkins-ci HOST_NAME=www.${ENVIRONMENT}.devops.co.uk npm run test${BROWSER}BrowserStackFromJenkins -- -c ${CONCURRENCY} -t "${TEST_NAME}"

elif [ "${FIXTURE_NAME}" != "All" ]
then
    NODE_ENV=jenkins-ci HOST_NAME=www.${ENVIRONMENT}.devops.co.uk npm run test${BROWSER}BrowserStackFromJenkins -- -c ${CONCURRENCY} -f "${FIXTURE_NAME}"

else
    NODE_ENV=jenkins-ci HOST_NAME=www.${ENVIRONMENT}.devops.co.uk npm run test${BROWSER}BrowserStackFromJenkins -- -c ${CONCURRENCY}
fi
```

Comment: Can you try ` testcafe ie tests/sample-fixture.js -t "${TEST_NAME}"`?

Comment: try to print before using to debug the `echo $TEST_NAME`

Comment: My solution has been added to original post.